# How to get a color from a specific pixel on HTML page in topmost element?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, document

I want to do the same as `canvasContext.getImageData(X,Y,1,1)`, but for an overall document (not a canvas), to get a color from a specific pixel on the document in topmost visible element.

I tried to do `document.getImageData(1,1,1,1)` on console to get the color from the pixel on the top left corner of the document, but it resulted in an error `Uncaught TypeError: document.getImageData is not a function`.
I also tried to get to do the same for the window `window.getImageData(1,1,1,1)`, but it resulted in a similar error `Uncaught TypeError: window.getImageData is not a function`.

So I can't use `getImageData(X,Y,1,1)` to get a color from a specific pixel on the document.

Does anyone have ideas on how do I get the color from a pixel of a document? Preferrably without JQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to obtain the first pixel of a document directly, getImageData method works on canvas context so you can't use that on the document or window object.

One possible solution is creating a temporary canvas element. This solution also require html2canvas.js https://html2canvas.hertzen.com

```js
function getFirstPixelColor(callback) {
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  html2canvas(document.body, {canvas: canvas}).then(() => {
    const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    const firstPixelColor = {
      r: imageData.data[0],
      g: imageData.data[1],
      b: imageData.data[2],
      a: imageData.data[3]
    };
    callback(firstPixelColor);
  });
}

getFirstPixelColor((color) => {
  console.log(`First pixel color: rgba(${color.r}, ${color.g}, ${color.b}, ${color.a})`);
});
```